# Audio player with listview

Tags: java, android, android-listview

i have audio files when i'm play another file then previous file play continuously.
so if you have solution please let me know.

here is my main.java

public class MusicAndroidActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    buttonPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
    music = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.music);
  //  music.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,, str));

    music.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {

            switch (position){

                case 0:
                    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.hosannatamil);
                    mp.start();
                    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            mp.release();
                        }
                    });
                    break;

                case 1:
                    MediaPlayer mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.one_less);
                    mp1.start();
                    mp1.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            mp.release();
                        }
                    });
                    break;
                case 2:
                    MediaPlayer mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.words);
                    mp2.start();
                    mp2.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            mp.release();
                        }
                    });
                    break;



            }
}
    });
}
```

Comment: For every position why are you creating instance of `MediaPlayer`??

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually call *MediaPlayer.stop()* if you want to stop the playback.

If you want to start the same MediaPlayer again you have to call *.prepare()* before that.

For more information read the [reference page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) and look at the state diagram there.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
{
    //stop or pause your media player mediaPlayer.stop(); or mediaPlayer.pause();
    mediaPlayer.pause();
}
else
{
    mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

Put this Condition inside switch statements before mediaPlayer.start() also create a global reference of Media Player instead of creating three references like MediaPlayer mediaPlayer instead of MediaPlayer mp,mp1,mp2 etc,because you can create media Player object in the same reference as one condition must be true all the time,also put a default condition in the switch statement!